# Writing to .txt with WriteFile() C++

Tags: c++, winapi

(Using C++, Windows 10,  Microsoft Visual Studio 2017)

Hello, I am new to serial ports but trying to learn how to open, close, read, and write with them

Right now, I am trying to use the `CreateFile()` and `WriteFile()` functions to write to a txt file.

I created a .txt file called "write.txt" and saved it in my Documents folder. Then I added it to my project's source files via "Add" --> "Existing Item". The file is empty.

I wrote the program below, hoping I could write to the file, but after running then checking on the file, the file is still empty. The program compiles but I am guessing I have an error somewhere. Am I going about writing to a file correctly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
HANDLE write;
    write = CreateFile(TEXT("\\write.txt"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (write == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        DWORD errorWrite = GetLastError();
        printf("Error in opening file\n");
        printf("Error = 0x%x\n", errorWrite);
    }
    else {
        printf("Opening file successful\n");
    }
    WriteFile(write, "hello", 5, 0, 0);

    CloseHandle(write);

    return 0;
}
```

The output says the file was opened successfully, but the write.txt file remains empty. Any advice?

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: You are not accessing the text file that is located in your Documents folder. You are accessing a text file that is located at the root of the drive where the calling process's current working directory is currently pointing at. You need to explicitly query the OS for the path to the Documents folder (ie, via `SHGetFolderPath()` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()`), and then append your filename to that path.

Comment: Hmm, so should I add a .txt file to the folder containing my source files? I tried adding a .txt file in the Add New File option but I could not find an option for .txt. Edit, just found the option for adding a .txt, should I go with that ? Trying it now

Comment: Adding the file to your project has NO EFFECT WHATSOEVER on this code. Seems you need to read up on what the current working directory is, and how relative file paths work at runtime.

Comment: I see, I am very new to this, do you have any articles you know could help? Been browsing the web the past couple of weeks for this type of information but it is hard to know what exactly to look for as I am learning this on my own. Also, does this have a direct relation with serial ports? If I learn how to write to a .txt file will the same skillset be used for writing to a port ? Thank you again

Comment: The same APIs can be used (`CreateFile()` to open, `WriteFile()` to write, etc), but there are other requirements, too. You should read about [Communications Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/communications-resources) on MSDN.

Comment: @HusamChekfa -- Please note that your file handling functions are specific to the Windows API.  They are not standard C++ function calls, thus the editing of your tags to add `winapi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not accessing the text file that is located in your Documents folder. You are accessing a text file that is located at the root of the drive where the calling process's current working directory is currently pointing at.

You need to explicitly query the OS for the path to the Documents folder (ie, via [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shsetknownfolderpath)), and then append your filename to that path.

Also, you are calling `WriteFile()` incorrectly.  In particular, the `lpNumberOfBytesWritten` parameter is wrong:

> lpNumberOfBytesWritten
>
> A pointer to the variable that receives the number of bytes written when using a synchronous `hFile` parameter. `WriteFile` sets this value to zero before doing any work or error checking. Use NULL for this parameter if this is an asynchronous operation to avoid potentially erroneous results.
>
> **This parameter can be NULL only when the `lpOverlapped` parameter is not NULL.**

And, you are not doing any error handling on `WriteFile()`, either:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero (TRUE).
>
> If the function fails, or is completing asynchronously, the return value is zero (FALSE). To get extended error information, call the `GetLastError` function.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = {};

    HRESULT hRes = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, path);
    if (FAILED(hRes)) {
        printf("Can't get Documents folder path\nError = 0x%08x\n", hRes);
    }
    else {
        PathAppend(path, TEXT("write.txt"));

        HANDLE write = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (write == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            DWORD errorWrite = GetLastError();
            printf("Can't open file\nError = %u\n", errorWrite);
        }
        else {
            printf("File opened successful\n");

            DWORD written;
            if (!WriteFile(write, "hello", 5, &written, NULL)) {
                DWORD errorWrite = GetLastError();
                printf("Can't write to file\nError = %u\n", errorWrite);
            } else {
                printf("File written successful\n");
            }
            CloseHandle(write);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```